# Timezone for maintenance messages

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, timezone

> Stack Overflow will be down from 10 PM - 12 AM for maintenance.

is rather vague. It is *always* 10 PM - 12 AM *somewhere* (except in Iceland, where it is [always simply Friday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/always-friday-in-iceland)).

Should this be in UTC since that is the site's rolling day time? Or just maybe specify a timezone...

For example it is down "now" - is this the *same* maintenance window? Or is the site kaput? My assumption is the former, but...

---

Edit: well damn me if I don't have access to that menu option. So self-fixed (yee-hah). But note to team; please include the timezone ;-p

Comment: They are usually PST, actually

Comment: indeed.  i get the same message and... well, midnight was either an hour ago or 23 hours from now...

Comment: Great!, Looks fixed now. I can see PST

Comment: Maybe change it to GMT/UTC? Why have it in PST when **all** of the other times are in GMT?

Comment: @Koper - there's a separate thread about that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40279/change-timezone-for-maintenance-messages-to-utc-gmt-based

Comment: There wasn't when I posted my comment.

Comment: i love how someone has voted to close this as a duplicate of a question that was *inspired by* this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd actually like to see this implemented to display the time in the logged-on user's timezone if possible. I don't want to subtract (or is it add?) four hours (or is it three?) to know when you're going to be down! Making me think should be a crime!

But seriously, I'm only suggesting this because it sounds easy to do and seems convenient.

Comment: @Changing - despite appearances that would not be easy with the current implementation. I'd settle for UTC personally ;-p

Comment: It's funny that UTC is used fr ll the other stuff and not localized, but the site maintenance messages are not converted to UTC.

Comment: @Marc - Fair enough. I agree about settling for UTC.

Answer (score 1):

Can we start a new tag?

`site-down-bored-must-post`

More relevant to the question, either specifying the time as PST, or converting it to UTC would be the two best options.

You could use the [World Time Clock](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedform.html) as well.

Comment: UTC makes just so much sense. People generally know their own local offset, but if it PST then most of the world needs to apply 2 offsets (or know the difference).

Comment: They already added the PST to the message.

Comment: see question update ;-p