# Change timezone for maintenance messages to UTC

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, timezone, maintenance

In response to [Timezone for maintenance messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40275/timezone-for-maintenance-messages), the team now shows timezone of PST for maintenance messages.

Since that is tagged as status-complete, I'm starting another request to show these messages in UTC/GMT timezone.

I'm at the timezone of GMT +8hr, PST makes no sense to me really.

Comment: Yeah, PST make no sense to me too as i'm at the timezone of GMT + 5:30Hrs.

Comment: PST makes complete sense to me, as I err ... live there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Agreed - almost everyone knows where they are relative to UTC, but asking people to add in another factor (and get it the right way round) is a bit pointless. It's *particuarly* tricky around this time of year, when there's a DST transition around the corner for many of us, but different people will experience it at different times.

The fact that the rest of SO (e.g. the rep cap and badges) revolve around UTC also means it would increase general consistency.

It's not exactly a *big* deal, but it would be nice to take a UTC-centric approach wherever possible, IMO.

Comment: +1 especially if you're 9hrs and 21 minutes out

Answer (score 5):

I **wish** I could have like this, just wish, nothing serious :-)

**before 3 hour**

```
Stack Overflow will be down in next 3 to 5 hour for maintenance.
```

**maintenence started 10 minutes ago**

```
Stack Overflow is down 10 minutes ago for maintenance, and it will take around 2 hours.
```

**5 minutes after maintenence**

```
Stack Overflow was down till last 5 minutes for maintenance, now enjoy!
```

Comment: I kinda like this suggestion. Though I will also prefer the absolute UTC times are displayed.

Comment: i say keep it going: "Stack Overflow was down for maintenance last Tuesday" "Stack Overflow was down for maintenance three weeks and two days ago".  It could be kind of like those construction sites "X days without an accident" signs.